# Correlation map in GrADS

Tags: grads

I am new in GrADS and I am trying to plot a field of correlation between two variables ([Precipitation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7DHSYWwuDH_SWFJX3B5M2NfNHc/view?usp=sharing) and [Temperature](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7DHSYWwuDH_MGVmQVhTczFpQVU/view?usp=sharing)) but I could not make it. I have tried with some libraries but it neither works.

Can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you have tried with the method given here. You can use fcorr.gs script. In another way you can use CDO.

http://www.atmos.umd.edu/~bguan/grads/GrADS_Scripts.html

Answer (score 1):

See the following links:

[1] Spatial Correlation
http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/gadoc/gradfuncscorr.html

[2] Temporal correlation
http://cola.gmu.edu/grads/gadoc/gradfunctcorr.html

You can also use cdo:

```
cdo fldcor  infile1 infile2 outfile
cdo timcor  infile1 infile2 outfile
```

See this link for details:

https://code.zmaw.de/projects/cdo/embedded/index.html#x1-5150002.9.1